# Ibm mq "Failed to connect to queue manager"

Tags: websphere, mq

need your help.

Given:

- 2 identical environments and configs, spring boot app and jms mq as queue manager;
- After a few differencies in code caught :

> Blockquote
> JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager
>
> JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED')
> reason '2397' ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR').
>
> Stack includes: Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException:
> CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9641: Remote CipherSpec error for channel '

Ibm docs suggests some reasons:

- Cipher spec mismatch6
- No cipher enabled on client\manager.

In a local env I'm able  to set ssl-cipher-spec and see its value through actuator.
But building engineers accuse code in some bugs.
I can't see major differences which could affect it, but if you were in my shoes , what would you advice?

Comment: Which version of IBM MQ jar files are you using? Which version of Java are using? Is it Oracle java? Are all these the same for both environments?

Answer (score 1):

You have mismatch between value CiphaerSpec value set on mq channel, and a CipherSuite value set within java application. The actual string value also depends on version of JAVA. See [table 1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q113220_.htm) for CipherSpec - CipherSuite mapping.

Also be aware that in modern MQ versions some combinations are [deprecated](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014260_.html)